# Attachment limit size by official Postal Service like "Postmark"

Tags: sendgrid, mailchimp, nodemailer, mailgun, postmark

I have connected my react app with my Postmark server to receive webhooks, but attachment limit size is only 10MB, in my case I would need more than that, at least around 20MB or bigger.
Does anyone know which platform can provide me this?

I have connected my react app with my Postmark server to receive webhooks, but attachment limit size does not meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some services with higher attachment limit:

- SendGrid: [30MB](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/limitations)
- Amazon SES V2: [40MB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/amazon-ses-v2-supports-email-size-40mb-inbound-outbound-emails-default/)
- Mailgun: [25MB](https://www.mailgun.com/legal/terms/#:%7E:text=Requirements%20include%2C%20but%20are%20not,it%20may%20be%20permanently%20lost.)

However, when attachments get this large, you may not want to embed them within the email:

- **Email Client:** Even if the email reaches the recipient's inbox, their email client may struggle to handle very large attachments. This can lead to slow performance, freezing, or crashing of the email client.
- **Recipient Email Server Limitations:** Even if your email service allows large emails, the recipient's email server may have its own size limitations
- **Storage Space:** Large attachments can quickly fill up email inboxes, which may have limited storage capacity.

I don't know your application requirements, but a better alternative would be to include a link to the attachment in your email and may give a heads-up to the users about the size of the attachment.

---

You may want to consider uploading an attachment to the cloud, for example:

- [Cloudflare R2](https://www.cloudflare.com/developer-platform/r2/)
- [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)
- [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage)

---

Additionally, you could look into using dedicated file sharing services, such as:

- [Mega](https://mega.io/)
- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)
- [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)
- [OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage)